# New feeds in chat from relevant tags on other SE sites

Tags: discussion, chat, site-crossover

Following the suggestion in [this meta post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1912/11365), some new feeds have been added to the [Academia chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/academia). The feed will post in the room each time a new question is posted on one of these tags:

- [career-development](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development?sort=newest&pageSize=15) on Mathematics SE
- [career](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/career?sort=newest&pageSize=15) on MathOverflow
- [career](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career?sort=newest&pageSize=15) on Theoretical Computer Science SE
- [academia](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academia?sort=newest&pageSize=15) on Cross Validated
- [graduate-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-education?sort=newest&pageSize=15) and [undergraduate-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate-education?sort=newest&pageSize=15) on Math Educators SE

These specific tags were chosen because:

- The content of most of the questions in them is highly related to the areas that are in the scope of Academia, and
- They are fairly low-volume (we don’t want to overwhelm chat)

The purpose of this meta post is for users to give feedback on the feeds in chat: “I hate this and want all the feeds to go away,” “I want X tag on Y site to also be added because Z,” etc.

As each of these feeds is posted by its own dedicated user, you can get rid of them on a per-feed basis by simply ignoring the respective user.

Comment: My goodness: this means chat might actually be used on a regular basis!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add:

- [research](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) on Mathematics SE.
- [research-process](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-process) on Biology SE
- [research-practice](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-practice) on Theoretical Computer Science SE
- [education-research](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education-research) on Math Educators SE
- [research](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) on Computer Science SE

Comment: The CS Theory tag looks good. The Math and Biology tags have many questions that are too math- and biology- specific, and the CS tag seems to have many questions that are low-quality or not suitable for SE. I feel like the education-research questions on Math Educators that are relevant will mostly also be tagged with undergraduate-education or graduate-education. (I don't think we're as interested in general education-research questions.)

Comment: I agree that the tags from Math, CS and Biology seem to be misused – pretty much like our [tag:research] tag. If I had editing privileges on one of those sites, I would probably clean them up. And as with all those feeds, we have to expect questions that are not interesting for us at all.