# Dedicated "This belongs on Cross Validated" off-topic option?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Inspired by, but not particularly picking on, this question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/65930/revisions

We currently have a very small list of default "off-topic" options - namely, just "This should be in meta".

It seems to be that we get a somewhat steady stream of stats questions, almost all of which belong on Cross Validated. Is there enough cause to add that as one of the defaults?

Comment: [Alternative suggestion](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/2012/7734) to prevent such questions before they are asked and for many other topics.

Answer (score 5):

In the last 90 days, we have [migrated one question to Cross Validated](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (image here for those who do not possess the necessary privileges to see the migration statistics page):

[image: migration stats page]

I think we need a history of regular well-received migrations before adding it as a migration path in the "close" interface. From [When should we consider adding a default migration path?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196/when-should-we-consider-adding-a-default-migration-path):

> Single digit migrations in the last 90 days and/or rejection rates that can order a drink without ID are signs that the path will be a waste of time to establish.

If you believe a post should be migrated away, vote to close it with a custom close reason and *also* flag the question for moderator attention and say where you think the question should be migrated to. See [this post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1943/11365) for more details on when to use this kind of flag and when not to.

Note that we should *not* migrate posts that are of such poor quality that they are likely to be closed for other reasons on the target site, e.g. questions that are too broad or too vague to be answered in their current state. For those questions, the OP needs to improve the post *before* we will consider migrating it (see the [Don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/254250) rule.)

Comment: More importantly, note that we only have a total of three custom close reasons. To add one right now requires deleting one of the existing ones.

Comment: @aeismail I think "Belongs on Cross Validated" would anyways be a migration path, not one of the three close reasons.

Comment: @ff524 How do we get that "history of regular well-recieved migrations" if we can only see 90 days?

Comment: @Fomite by "regular" I meant "more often than once or twice in 90 days." See [When should we consider adding a default migration path?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196/when-should-we-consider-adding-a-default-migration-path).